# jQuery kwicks. Li not expand (resize)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, kwicks

I try integratte kwicks slider (like image gallery) into mainpage of site (See dev.podmoscvoy.ru)
But after redraw ul>li (with image) i have not any reaction.
Used last kwicks version code.

Code is standart for kwicks

```
<div id="metaslider_container_99">
    <div id="metaslider_99" class="kwicksslider">
        <ul class="kwicks kwicks-horizontal" style="width:700px;height:400px">
            <li >here is image definition</li>
           <li >here is image definition</li>
            <li >here is image definition</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

code JS

```
$(function() {
      $('#metaslider_99>ul.kwicks').kwicks({ 
         behavour:'menu'
      });
});
```

No javascrip errors, but kwicks not played. Please help

Comment: Try doing this in jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net to reproduce the problem. More people can help that way.

Comment: I try to reproduce my situation on JSFiddle. You can see it on [link](http://jsfiddle.net/he9kmpzd/12/)
It is same - images draw  with correct size, UL have a new class kwicks-processed but it is all. Not reaction on mouse, not animation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo (опечатка, в общем :)). I'm talking about example of the code at fiddle and in your question..

```
behavior: 'slideshow'
```

not

```
behavour: 'slideshow'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `class="kwicks-selected"` to the first `<li>` element.